# google-play-scraper and node errors

Tags: javascript, google-play

I'm trying to use google play scraper to scrape 100 applications, and show the results of those applications with all the permissions.

I've written multiple .js files to run via node, and all of them have returned errors.

I am not sure how to use promises here, so this code will not return any results, but does not give me a 404

```js
var scraper = require("google-play-scraper")

// get a list of apps
var apps = scraper.search({
  term: "foo",
  num: 100,
})

var meta = []

// function to get meta from the app
function getMeta(item) {
    var appId = item.appId
    var metadata = scraper.permissions({
      appId: appId,
    })
    // append metadata to meta somehow idk js that well anymore
}

// console.log(apps)
// await apps.forEach(getMeta)

async function printFiles () {
  const files = await apps.forEach(getMeta)

  for await (const file of fs.readFile(file, 'utf8')) {
    console.log(contents)
  }
}
```

the code sample below gives a 404 pointing to the location of the installed module

```js
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.app({appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies'})
  .then(console.log, console.log);
```

Here is the error for the second code sample.

```
Error: App not found (404)
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\node_modules\google-play-scraper\lib\utils\request.js:44:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
{
  status: 404
}
```